# Interpreting $0\xrightarrow{}\text{Im }f, 0\xrightarrow{}\text{Ker }f$ in examples of exact sequences for showing $\text{Im }f_{n+1}=\text{Ker }f_n.$

Tags: abelian-groups, exact-sequence

The following is taken from *Modules an approach to linear algebra* by Blyth

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

[image]

$\textbf{Example:}$ If $f:A\to B$ is a morphism of abelian groups then we have the exact sequence

$0\xrightarrow{}\text{Ker }f\xrightarrow{i}A\xrightarrow{\sharp}A/\text{Ker }f\xrightarrow{}0\quad (*)$

in which $i$ is the canonical incolusion and $\sharp$ is the canonical epimorphsm.  Likewise, we havve an exact sequence

$0\xrightarrow{}\text{Im }f\xrightarrow{} B\xrightarrow{}B/\text{Im }f\xrightarrow{}0\quad (**)$

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

I don't understand the notation for the maps $0\xrightarrow{}\text{Ker }f$ and $0\xrightarrow{}\text{Im }f.$  Normally, if I have a morphism $0\to M,$ where $M$ is some algebraic object, then $0\to M,$ would mean $0\mapsto 0\in M.$  But for the case of $0\xrightarrow{}\text{Ker }f\xrightarrow{i}A,$ do I interpret as follow:

Givevn $0\to \text{Ker }f $ to mean $0\mapsto 0\in\text{Ker }f,$ and $f$ being a morphism of abelian groups from $A$ to $B$ gives $f(0)=0,$ where $0$ denotes the identity element. Then $\text{Im }(0\to \text{Ker }f)=\text{Ker }f=\{0\}.$ But $i:\text{Ker }f=0\to A:=i:0\mapsto A,$ and this implies $\text{Ker }i=\text{Ker }f=\{0\}$ hence $\text{Im}(0\to \text{Ker } f)=\text{Ker }i.$

Similarly, for $0\xrightarrow{}\text{Im }f\xrightarrow{}B.$ in $(**).$ $0\xrightarrow{}\text{Im }f$ means $0\mapsto 0\in \text{Im }f,$ and $f$ being a morphism of abelian groups from $A$ to $B,$ then $f(0)=0$ where $0$ denotes the identity element. So $\text{Im }(0 \to \text{Im }f)=\text{Ker }f=\{0\}.$ But $\text{Ker }(\text{Im }f\to B)=\{0\}.$  Hence $\text{Im }(0 \to \text{Im }f)=\text{Ker }f=\text{Ker }(\text{Im }f\to B)=\{0\}.$  But what happens if $\text{Ker}f\neq \{0\}?$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where did $\text{Im }(0\to \text{Ker }f)=\text{Ker }f$ come from?

Comment: @EricWofsey I thought since $f(0)=0$ then I can conclude that $\text{Im }(0\to \text{Ker }f)=\text{Ker }f=\{0\}.$  I am guessing I am either not expressing myself clearly, or I am not understanding the notations correctly, or something is wrong with my logical reasoning.

Comment: Why do you think you can conclude that?

Comment: @EricWofsey the purpose of my post is trying to understand if I am given a sequence of morphisms, either $(*)$ or $(**)$, for the first two segments from the left of the two, how do I show either $\text{Im}(0\to \text{Ker}f)=\text{Ker}(\text{Ker}f \xrightarrow{i} A ),$ and $\text{Im}(0\to \text{Im}f)=\text{Ker}(\text{Im}f \xrightarrow{} B ),$

Answer (score 0):

I believe your second SES is $$0 \rightarrow \text{Im}(f) \rightarrow B \rightarrow B / \text{Im}(f) \rightarrow 0$$

Since Ker(f) $\hookrightarrow A $ is an inclusion, it is injective. This is how we should read the sequence $$ 0 \rightarrow \text{Ker}(f) \stackrel{i}{ \rightarrow }A $$

It says that $i$ is an injective map. As you say, $0$ maps to $0$.

Similarly for the second sequence.

Comment: I edit my post and also included a screenshot of the example.  For $0\xrightarrow{}\text{Im }f\xrightarrow{} B$, do I interpret $\text{Im }f\xrightarrow{} B$ to be a surjective map?

Comment: No, $0 \rightarrow \text{Im}(f) \rightarrow B$ exact implies that the inclusion of the image of f into B is injective

Comment: $\text{Im}(f)\to B$ is an inclusion map?  In both cases $(*),(**),$ is $f(0)=0?$  I know that $0\to \text{Im}(f),$ $0\to \text{Ker}(f)$ to mean respectively $0\mapsto 0\in \text{Im}(f),$ and $0\mapsto 0\in\text{Ker}(f).$  But we don't know if $\text{Ker}(f)=\{0\}$ in both cases or at least in the second one, where as the first, we don't know if $\{0\}$ is the only element in the kernel of $f$.  Or am I missing some subtle detail?  I am just not clear on how to relate notations: $0\to \text{Im}(f),$ $0\to \text{Ker}(f)$ back to $f$.

Comment: Whether $f(0)=0$ is a separate notion, but this is also true. The important thing to grasp is that we are considering $\text{Ker}(f)$ as a submodule of $A$. Similarly, we are viewing $\text{Im}(f)$ as a submodule of $B$. We are not saying whether $\text{Ker}(f)=0$, just that the *inclusion* of $\text{Ker}(f)$ into $A$ is injective.

Comment: $\text{Im}(f)$ into $B$ is also injective, which is always the case?

Comment: If $0 \rightarrow \text{Im}(f) \rightarrow B$ is exact, then you bet!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149122/discussion-between-locally-trivial-and-seth).

Comment: but if I am simply given $0\to \text{Im}(f)\to B$ and don't know whether it is exact.  Then I can't assume that $\text{Im}(f)\to B$ is injective?  I do know that $\text{Im}(f)\subset B.$  But I am not sure from that simple fact, I can conclude injectivity.  I am sorry if I am being pedantic on the language here.